# Swift Open Link in Safari

Tags: webview, swift, safari

I am currently opening the link in my app in a `WebView`, but I'm looking for an option to open the link in **Safari** instead.

Answer (score 412, accepted):

It's not "baked in to Swift", but you can use standard `UIKit` methods to do it. Take a look at UIApplication's [`openUrl(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl) *(deprecated)* and [`open(_:options:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open).

**Swift 4 + Swift 5 (iOS 10 and above)**

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

**Swift 3 (iOS 9 and below)**

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com") else { return }
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Comment: Is there any chance from app store if we add some purchasing URL like this?

Comment: In iOS 10.0 you must now add options and handler:
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"http://www.google.com")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

Comment: @gabicuesta You actually don't have to provide options and completionHandler, they default to [:] and nil, respectively

Comment: iOS14 not open link in Safari if setting "Default Browser" set to other like Google Chrome etc.

Answer (score 95):

New with iOS 9 and higher you can present the user with a `SFSafariViewController` (see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller)). Basically you get all the benefits of sending the user to Safari without making them leave your app. To use the new SFSafariViewController just:

```
import SafariServices
```

and somewhere in an event handler present the user with the safari view controller like this:

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The safari view will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks! Everyone who wants to show the Safari browser in an app extension should use this code. Accessing the `sharedApplication` property in app extension is forbidden. For more: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2

Comment: outstanding solution

Comment: Apple is sometimes rejecting apps from the store for using the old openURL method. This should now be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 5**

[Swift 5: Check using `canOpneURL` if valid then it's open.](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2019/08/open-link-in-safari-swift-5.html)

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/") else {
     return
}

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: How to verfiy and avoid reopening app Safari if it has been already opened. When lauching I got a warning/error ```LAUNCH: Launch failure with -10652/ <FSNode 0x10d50cf90> { isDir = y, path = '/Applications/Safari.app' } ```

Answer (score 21):

UPDATED for Swift 4: (credit to Marco Weber)

```
if let requestUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.iSecurityPlus.com") {
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(requestUrl as URL) 
}
```

OR go with more of swift style using `guard`:

```
guard let requestUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.iSecurityPlus.com") else {
    return
}

UIApplication.shared.openURL(requestUrl as URL)
```

Swift 3:

You can check NSURL as optional implicitly by:

```
if let requestUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.iSecurityPlus.com") {
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(requestUrl)
}
```

Comment: It should be (requestUrl!)

Comment: Amit, No, because it's done explicitly as I have explained it is guarantee that requestUrl exist if let requestUrl = ...

Comment: Actually, it is. In Swift 2.

Comment: Amit, here is code directly from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html: You can also use an implicitly unwrapped optional with optional binding, to check and unwrap its value in a single statement:

if let definiteString = assumedString {
    print(definiteString)
}
// prints "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."

Comment: My way works perfectly fine for me, and this is for Swift 2, remember that.

Comment: yes, there are many way to do things. Learn the reason why you should use certain code in a situation instead of being a stubborn brat saying, "I'm right, therefore your wrong" mentality. Seems like you are new to programming this is my advise to you kid.

Comment: Amit: No, it doesn't work, you are simply wrong. In Swift 2 or 1.2. And no wonder, requestUrl is not an optional so you can't unwrap it with !.

Comment: I like this method better than the one from Mike S, because you do the nil check before sending the request.

Comment: updated for Swift4:
`if let requestUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.iSecurityPlus.com") {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(requestUrl as URL)
        }`

Comment: @CodeOverRide , agreed with this method cover all aspect, optional binding is a safe way to implement anything in swift as it prevents from unwanted crashes

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3 & IOS 10.2**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

> Swift 3 & IOS 10.2

Comment: But note that using this version will stop your app running on iOS 9 and previous unless you version check it

Answer (score 11):

since iOS 10 you should use:

```
guard let url = URL(string: linkUrlString) else {
    return
}
    
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 1.2:

```
@IBAction func openLink {    
    let pth = "http://www.google.com"
    if let url = NSURL(string: pth){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.0:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your using SwiftUI:

```
Link("Stack Overflow", destination: URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com/")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

IOS 11.2 Swift 3.1- 4

```
let webView = WKWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") else { return }
    webView.frame = view.bounds
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(webView)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
            let host = url.host, !host.hasPrefix("www.google.com"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            print(url)
            print("Redirected to browser. No need to open it locally")
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            print("Open it locally")
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    } else {
        print("not a user click")
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```