# How create an iPhone app that just starts a website

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I create an iPhone app that just starts a website in the default browser?
I'm not looking for a browser inside an app, just goto the pre-programmed website and close the app.
What do I need to get this accomplished?

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945324/swift-open-link-in-safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is homescreen shortcuts you can create out of Safari. Unfortunately to have a native app that just starts the webbrowser is not possible.

Here is how you create a homescreen shortcut:

**1. Tap the share button in Safari**

[image]

**2. Tap "Add to Homescreen"**

[image]

**3. Confirm or change shortcut title**

[image]

**4. Done. See the shortcut on your homescreen**

[image]